# How to fix broken image?

Tags: php, ios, image, forms

I have created an ios app that captures an image then uploads it to a server I  have.

I do this through **PHP that takes the image data into a form**.

The web version of the form works perfectly and I can see the image.

**The ios app version is defective since I get a broken image.**

Why is this happening?

I have checked that they do contain the same data (When entering it into a BASE64 converter I see the same image), the same file path is being created (I create the file path and insert the data through the PHP form).

Any ideas?

As requested here is some code

**Here is the web version PHP form var_dump output:**

http://pastebin.com/w6q2W9gK

**Here is the iOS app binary string being sent to the PHP form:**

http://pastebin.com/RtEn4xVA

Comment: needs more info and code examples. if your app is failing to detect that it is an image, you can use create image from string to convert binary string to image resource

Comment: To clarify I've converted the image to a binary string so I can get it to the PHP form. This works since when that same binary string (copy and pasted) is entered from my website to the PHP form shows an image. Sorry for the lack of code, the var_data output and binary string was too long for stackoverflow to handle

Comment: paste bin it and i can tell you whats wrong with the data.

Comment: Ditto to what they are saying - there is a large number of potential issues. Paste some code please

Comment: Okay thanks so much I will paste some code now